# Using grams instead of kilograms in terminal velocity equation

Tags: experimental-physics, velocity, laboratory-safety

I am conducting an experiment verifying the relationship between terminal velocity and other factors:

$v_t = \sqrt{\frac{2mg}{\rho AC_d}}.$ (All values in SI units.)

Suppose that I have all my measurements of mass $m$ in grams. Then, is it correct to say:

> The theoretical equation for $v_t$ is $$v_t = \sqrt{\frac{2mg}{1000\rho AC_d}},$$ where the mass $m$ is in grams.

Can I use this modified formula for grams in the lab?

Comment: it should work ok

Comment: $mg$ is the force of gravity (aka weight) on the object in question.  If you use grams for mass, you still need to use appropriate conversion factors to arrive at Newtons.  Also, no matter what units you use, your answer must be dimensionally consistent.  I also note that $m/1000$ IS kg when $m$ is expressed in grams.

Comment: the usual and better way ist just to put in your g as $ 10^{– 3}kg $ wich is in accord with your formula if all the other constants have no additional g.

Answer (score 1):

So long as all the other values are still in SI units, things should work as you expect. That is because mass in kg is precisely equal to mass in grams divided by 1000.

But note that if you use grams for all the other units i.e. density $\rho$ in grams/m^3 or grams/cm^3, then you will have to appropriately scale for those changes in units as well.